# Calling a function from a PHP file to another PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I created a file called "page.php" with the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            require 'form.php';
        ?>
        <a href="#" onclick="call_popup('form_container')">Click this link!</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

And I created another file "form.php" with the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function call_popup (container_id) {
        var id= document.getElementById(container_id);
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
<div id="form_container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="button" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to call the "call_popup(container_id)" function in "page.php" which is defined in "form.php". When I click the "Click this link!" of the anchor tag it gives an error saying `call_popup('form_container')` not found!

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this in the beginning of "page.php":

```
require_once("form.php");
```

But I am not sure that works with JavaScript functions..

Try create a JavaScript file, "file.js", and reference it in two PHP files:

```
<script src="file.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your JavaScript code in a different file - for example `file.js`.

Include this file in all HTML files you wish to use your code in, in the `head` section:

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="call_popup('form_container')">Click this link!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's better practice to separate client-side code (JavaScript) from server-side code (PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
require 'form.php';
```

inside the `php` tags use

```
include ()
```

Comment: I tried include('form.php') and require('form.php').. i tried both.. but its not working it is still giving the same error!!

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your setup on my local XAMPP and it works (though it's not the best practice to mix JavaScript and HTML code). Are you sure the "require" call works? Do you see the form defined in "form.php" in your browser?

Maybe you just get the path to "form.php" wrong and have PHP error messages disabled on the server (not uncommon in a production environment). In that case PHP would die due to a missing file but won't throw any message that something went wrong...